# Como trabalhar com objetos em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho dois objetos, `objeto1` e `objeto2` e quero atribuir todos os valores do `objeto1` ao `objeto2`, mas quando uso `objeto2 = objeto1` e altero algum valor do `objeto2` o `objeto1` também é alterado pois possuem o mesmo endereço. Como criar um novo objeto com os mesmos valores de uma forma rápida?

Comment: Uma opção simples - mas não muito eficiente - é serializar e de-serializar esse objeto usando JSON: `objeto2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objeto1));` Nota: só funciona se seu objeto não tiver ciclos.

Answer (score 0):

```
var objeto1 = new Object();
var objeto2 = new Object();

// objeto1 = objeto2 funciona como apontamento
// quando é nova instancia de objeto então tem que instanciar e não referenciar
```

Caso de clonar objeto já preenchido:

```
    function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

var d1 = new Date();

/* Wait for 5 seconds. */
var start = (new Date()).getTime();
while ((new Date()).getTime() - start < 5000);


var d2 = clone(d1);
alert("d1 = " + d1.toString() + "\nd2 = " + d2.toString());
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/3130590

Comment: Sim SnnepS muito obrigado pela sua resposta, mas o `objeto1` já está instanciado e preenchido, e eu gostaria de duplica-lo ao `objeto2` de forma independente.